# How do I understand the IUPAC naming of 9-methyl-3-[(2-methylimidazol-1-yl)methyl]-2,3-dihydro-1H-carbazol-4-one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds, amines

I'm having trouble understanding the IUPAC naming convention of **9-methyl-3-[(2-methylimidazol-1-yl)methyl]-2,3-dihydro-1H-carbazol-4-one**.

It would be great if you can help to breakdown the naming structure for me.

[image: 9-methyl-3-[(2-methylimidazol-1-yl)methyl]-2,3-dihydro-1H-carbazol-4-one]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to name the compound that is given in the question, first we need to identify the parent structure. Fortunately, there is a principal characteristic group (the ketone), thus it is clear that the parent structure is the part that includes this group.

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069),* retained names (also called trivial names) are used for various heterocycles with the maximum number of noncumulative double bonds. In Table 2.8 of the Blue Book, we find that the retained name for the parent structure of the given compound is **carbazole.**

Table 2.8 also shows the fixed numbering of carbazole. According to Rule P-14.4, this fixed numbering must be used. Therefore, the locant of the principal characteristic group is ‘4’. Since the principal characteristic group is expressed as a suffix, the given compound is a **carbazol-4-one.**

The original parent structure carbazole ($\ce{C12H9N}$) has the maximum number of noncumulative double bonds for this kind of structure. Compared to an ideal unsaturated compound, however, carbazole has one extra hydrogen somewhere. The position of this extra hydrogen must be indicated. A few different isomers are possible; for example, the original parent structure could be 9*H*-carbazole (i.e. with the extra hydrogen at the nitrogen).

[image: 9H-carbazole]

In the given compound, two double bonds of the original carbazole are missing. Thus, the parent structure is a bit more saturated with the equivalent of four additional hydrogen atoms ($\ce{C12H13N}$). Such saturation is described using ‘hydro’ prefixes. The locants of the original indicated hydrogen and the four additional hydrogens are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 9. The indicated hydrogen gets the lowest locant, so the name of the unsubstituted parent structure is **2,3,4,9-tetrahydro-1*H*-carbazole.**

[image: 2,3,4,9-tetrahydro-1H-carbazole]

In the substituted carbazol-4-one, however, the numbering is different because one of the double bonds was removed to make room for the ketone. According to Rule P-58.2.3, the indicated hydrogen is placed at the position that will accommodate this principal characteristic group. Therefore, the name becomes **1,2,3,9-tetrahydro-4*H*-carbazol-4-one.**

[image: 1,2,3,9-tetrahydro-4H-carbazol-4-one]

Finally, we can add the other substituents. There is a simple **methyl** group at the nitrogen (locant 9) and the complex substituent group **(2-methyl-1*H*-imidazol-1-yl)methyl** at position 3. Therefore, the complete name of the given compound is **9-methyl-3-[(2-methyl-1*H*-imidazol-1-yl)methyl]-1,2,3,9-tetrahydro-4*H*-carbazol-4-one.**

[image: 9-methyl-3-[(2-methyl-1H-imidazol-1-yl)methyl]-1,2,3,9-tetrahydro-4H-carbazol-4-one]